# Writablebitmap Indexed8 writepixels

Tags: c#

I try to change writablebitmap using writepixels() method, but it doesn't change any pixels.
it has following consructor

```
public void createWbm(int viewportW, int viewportH)
        {
            writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(
            viewportW,
            viewportH,
            96,
            96,
            PixelFormats.Indexed8,
            new BitmapPalette(Form1.form1.getColors()));
            i.Source = writeableBitmap;
        }
```

and I use this method calling leftbuttondown event, but there is not any change. Is it necessary to use two loops(outer for row of pixels and inner for columns ) to paint every pixle or it is possible use just writepixels() method? thanks

```
void BrushPixel(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] ColorData = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }; // B G R

    Int32Rect rect = new Int32Rect(
            (int)(e.GetPosition(i).X), 
            (int)(e.GetPosition(i).Y), 
            1, 
            1);

    writeableBitmap.WritePixels( rect, ColorData, 4, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly using it,

- at this format (8-bit) your array `ColorData` either represents an 1x4, 4x1 or 2x2 pixels image.
- therefore `rect` dimensions should match either of these sizes

Keep in mind that these are indices to colors in a palette, not BGR values as you've commented.

Here's a simple example :

[image]

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(100, 100, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Indexed8, BitmapPalettes.Halftone256);
        int width = 50;
        int height = 50;
        var pixels = new byte[width*height];
        var random = new Random();
        random.NextBytes(pixels);
        bitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), pixels, width, 0);
        Image1.Source = bitmap;
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication14.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
        UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <Grid>
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">
            <Image x:Name="Image1" Stretch="None" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note : at this format `stride` parameter always equals `width` because a pixel length in bytes is 1.

I strongly suggest you to use [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) instead, it makes `WriteableBitmap` manipulation way easier. Beware that it supports only `PixelFormats.Pbgra32` but unless you really have a specific reason to use 8-bit I can only recommend it, it can draw many primitives such as lines, rectangles, circles etc ...